# Store output of for loop into an array or variable

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, for-loop

I have a for loop as shown below. I need the whole output of the loop added into an array or variable.

```
for i in $ip
do
  curl -s $i:9200
done
```

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
# declare an array
declare -a arr=()

for i in $ip
do
  # append each curl output into our array
  arr+=( "$(curl -s $i:9200)" )
done

# check array content
declare -p arr
```

It is important to use quotes around curl comment to avoid splitting words of `curl` command's output into multiple array entries. With quotes all of the curl output will become a single entry in the array.

Comment: Great one @anubhava.  I think it would be nice if you could explain why the curl command needs to be inside double quotes.

Comment: what I need is to add the output of that curl command to the array, Not the command itself.

Comment: @zozo6015: Using `$(...)` i.e command substitution we are adding output of `curl` command not the command itself.

Comment: Thanks @codeforester. I've added some explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+=`

```
declare -a output
for i in $ip
do
  output+=("$(curl -s $i:9200)")
done
```

Comment: I get `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: Yep. Just tested it out, and apparently you can't have a space before `+=`. Well, you learn something new every day

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the output of any command, including a compound command, by enclosing it in `$()`.  Using that technique, you can capture the output of your `for` loop in a variable like so:

```
results=$(
  for i in $ip
  do
    curl -s $i:9200
  done
)
```

In principle, capturing into an array can be done in similar fashion, but handling element delimiters appropriately could prove difficult.